# pandas concatenate duplicate rows based on single column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove duplicates values and blanks in my dataframe, and then reorder all the values so that in a row, all column values end with same number:

**THIS IS MY CURRENT DATAFRAME:**

```
    brand   code   des   price   year
0  brand1  code1  des1  price1  year1
1  brand2  code2        price2       
2  brand3  code3  des3  price3  year3
3  brand4  code4        price4       
4  brand5  code5  des5  price5  year5
5  brand6  code6        price6       
6          code2  des2          year2
7          code4  des4          year4
8          code6  des6          year6
```

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT AS OUTPUT:**

```
    brand   code   des   price   year
0  brand1  code1  des1  price1  year1
1  brand2  code2  des2  price2  year2
2  brand3  code3  des3  price3  year3
3  brand4  code4  des4  price4  year4
4  brand5  code5  des5  price5  year5
5  brand6  code6  des6  price6  year6
```

This is the code I wrote, if someone can guide me how can I do it, that would be really appreciated:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'code': ['code1','code2','code3','code4','code5','code6','code2','code4','code6'],
'des': ['des1','','des3','','des5','','des2','des4','des6'],
'price': ['price1','price2','price3','price4','price5','price6','','',''],
'year': ['year1','','year3','','year5','','year2','year4','year6'],
'brand': ['brand1','brand2','brand3','brand4','brand5','brand6','','','']
}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.apply()` on each column and then for each column series, use [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the sorted unique item list (with empty string skipped) and then use `pd.Series` to recreate the columns.

```
import numpy as np

df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.unique(x[x!=''])))
```

Output:

```
    code   des   price   year   brand
0  code1  des1  price1  year1  brand1
1  code2  des2  price2  year2  brand2
2  code3  des3  price3  year3  brand3
3  code4  des4  price4  year4  brand4
4  code5  des5  price5  year5  brand5
5  code6  des6  price6  year6  brand6
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? First fill the empty space with `np.nan` then drop the na rows using apply

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))

code    des     price   year    brand
0   code1   des1    price1  year1   brand1
1   code2   des3    price2  year3   brand2
2   code3   des5    price3  year5   brand3
3   code4   des2    price4  year2   brand4
4   code5   des4    price5  year4   brand5
5   code6   des6    price6  year6   brand6
6   code2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   code4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   code6   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```